# How to set a proxy in kde?

Tags: configuration, kde, proxy, tor

I'm using kde and tor. I'm could not set tor ip into the network manager.

Network manager has not any option for proxy.

Comment: Are you sure there is no option `Network Proxy` in `Network`. This time browse `/ -> usr -> share -> applications` and open the icon `Network` you would get `Network Proxy` as an option. Did you try this?

Comment: The KDE environment has got a different location for setting the proxy.  You can simply type Proxy into the K-start menu, and it will find it for you.

Answer (score 2):

In the KDE K menu `Search` enter "Proxy".

Or K-menu, Application, Settings, System Settings, Network Settings, Proxy

You can also get to the KDE global settings using by starting the System Settings program from a terminal, the command is "systemsettings", then go to Network Settings and then Proxy.

Enter your Proxy configuration there.  Many applications will automatically and dynamically use these settings.

Comment: for some reason this is not working

Answer (score -2):

**Here are the steps to set proxy**

- Search **Network** in *dash* ( you can also find the icon of `Network` in `/ -> usr -> share -> applications` just double click it to open )
- Then chose **Network Proxy** on the Window.
- Select <kbd>Manual</kbd> form the list. Set your proxy and
- <kbd>Apply System Wide</kbd>
- Thats it.

Hope this would be your solution.

Comment: The poster asked for the KDE environment.