# What configures the ~/.kde/share/config/kioslaverc proxy settings?

Tags: networking, 18.04, kubuntu, kde, proxy

In my `~/.kde/share/config/kioslaverc` I appear to have some proxy settings. I'm not clear where they came from. There's no where I can find in the KDE settings that reference these proxy settings. Some programs though, like Zoom, attempt to use them.

What are these settings, where do they get changed?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/342832/how-to-set-a-proxy-in-kde#444887 perhaps?

Comment: @ITGremlin Those aren't those settings. My proxy settings in KDE are empty, yet there was still something in that file.

Answer (score 0):

Try

> sudo gedit /etc/environment

[Credit](https://superuser.com/questions/1111538/how-do-i-configure-proxy-and-proxy-authentication-in-linux)